# Global Variables vs Parameters is Python Console Game

Tags: python, global-variables

I just looked over some code I wrote a while back and noticed something weird with global variables. For example in `update_board` I pass `board` as a parameter, and update it inside the function, but don't return the updated board, yet it still gets updated. So it appears I'm basically using a global value for `board`.

To be consistent, should I avoid passing the `board` parameter and use `global board` instead? I know globals are discouraged, but it's maybe at least better to be explicit about them. Or would it be better to replace instances of `update_board(board, row, col)` with `board = update_board(board, row, col)` and return `board` from `update_board` instead?

Or have I possibly hit upon a valid approach quite by accident as the code stands?

```
"""
Chomp - a strategy game
"""

import random
import time

NUM_ROWS = 5
NUM_COLS = 6

FILLED_SPOT = "#"
POISON_SPOT = "P"
EMPTY_SPOT = " "


def print_title():
    print(r"""
 ______     __  __     ______     __    __     ______  
/\  ___\   /\ \_\ \   /\  __ \   /\ "-./  \   /\  == \ 
\ \ \____  \ \  __ \  \ \ \/\ \  \ \ \-./\ \  \ \  _-/ 
 \ \_____\  \ \_\ \_\  \ \_____\  \ \_\ \ \_\  \ \_\   
  \/_____/   \/_/\/_/   \/_____/   \/_/  \/_/   \/_/   
""")


def print_instructions():
    print("Welcome to Chomp. Choose a square. All squares to the right")
    print("and downwards will be eaten. The computer will do the same.")
    print("The one to eat the poison square loses. Good luck!")
    print()


def who_goes_first():
    return random.choice(("computer", "human"))


def play_again():
    print("Would you like to play again (yes or no)?")
    return input().lower().startswith("y")


def print_matrix(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for elem in row:
            print(elem, end=EMPTY_SPOT)
        print()


def validate_user_input(player_choice, board):
    try:
        row, col = player_choice.split()
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad input: The input should be exactly two numbers separated by a space.")
        return False
    try:
        row = int(row)
        col = int(col)
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be two numbers, however non-digit characters were received.")
        return False

    if row < 0 or row > NUM_ROWS - 1:
        print(f"The first number must be between 0 and {NUM_ROWS - 1} but {row} was passed.")
        return False
    if col < 0 or col > NUM_COLS - 1:
        print(f"The second number must be between 0 and {NUM_COLS - 1} but {col} was passed.")
        return False
    if board[row][col] == EMPTY_SPOT:
        print("That square has already been eaten!")
        return False
    return True


def update_board(board, row, col):
    for i in range(row, len(board)):
        for j in range(col, len(board[i])):
            board[i][j] = EMPTY_SPOT


def get_human_move(board):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        player_choice = input("Enter the row and column number (counting from 0) of your choice,\
        \nseparated by a space: ")
        valid_input = validate_user_input(player_choice, board)
    row, col = player_choice.split()
    return int(row), int(col)


def get_computer_move(board):
    valid_move = False
    while not valid_move:
        row = random.randint(0, NUM_ROWS - 1)
        col = random.randint(0, NUM_COLS - 1)
        if board[row][col] == EMPTY_SPOT:
            continue
        else:
            valid_move = True
    return row, col


def main():
    game_over = False
    while not game_over:
        board = []
        for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
            row = []
            for j in range(NUM_COLS):
                row.append(FILLED_SPOT)
            board.append(row)

        board[0][0] = POISON_SPOT
        game_is_playing = True
        turn = who_goes_first()

        print_title()
        print_instructions()
        print_matrix(board)
        print()

        while game_is_playing:
            if turn == "human":
                # Human turn
                print("Human turn.")
                row, col = get_human_move(board)
                if board[row][col] == POISON_SPOT:
                    print()
                    print("Too bad, the computer wins!")
                    game_is_playing = False
                else:
                    update_board(board, row, col)
                    print()
                    print_matrix(board)
                    print()
                    turn = "computer"
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                # Computer turn
                row, col = get_computer_move(board)
                print(f"Computer turn. The computer chooses ({row}, {col})")
                print()
                if board[row][col] == POISON_SPOT:
                    print()
                    print("Yay, you win!")
                    game_is_playing = False
                else:
                    update_board(board, row, col)
                    print_matrix(board)
                    print()
                    turn = "human"

        if play_again():
            main()
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")
            game_over = True

main()
```

Comment: The function is *mutating* an object. That's a valid thing to do. Arguably that function should be a method of a `Board` class to keep things self-contained. You're on the path to discovering object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a global variable. Instead you have a locally scoped variable which you pass to your function.

When you create a variable you are just creating an alias to point to the memory location of an object. In the below code we are creating a list which is an object and has a string object inside it. We then create the name mylist and point it to the memory location of the list object.

```
mylist = [1]
```

When you then pass mylist to a function what happens is the function gets a copy of the memory location that mylist points to and the function sets its local variable to point to that memory location.

So when you do an action which mutates the object in that memory location then that update will be seen also by the variable name outside the function since both point to the same memory location.

If however you were to reassign soemthing to that variable in the function like create a new list then that wouldnt reflect in the variable outside the function. Since what would actually be happening is a new object would be created and the local scope variable would be pointed to it. that wouldnt change the memory address of the variable outside of the function which would still point to the original location.

```
def first():
    mylist = [1]
    print("mylist:", mylist)
    print("mylist id:", id(mylist))
    second(mylist)
    third(mylist)
    print("mylist:", mylist)
    print("mylist id:", id(mylist))

def second(second_list):
    #here the local function variable second_list points to the same memory location as mylist
    print("second id:", id(second_list))
    #Here we change the values in this memory location. So second list is still pointing to and change the data that my list points to
    #this is why mylist can see the change even though its not a global variable
    second_list.append(2)
    print("Second_list:", second_list)
    print("second id:", id(second_list))

def third(third_list):
    #here the local function variable third_list points to the same mermoy location as mylist
    print("third list:", third_list)
    print("third id:", id(third_list))
    #here we create a new object which will have a new memory lcaotion then we point the local variable third_list at it.
    #now third_list points to new memory location and not the same memory location as mylist.
    third_list=[3]
    print("third list:", third_list)
    print("third id:", id(third_list))

first()
```

below is the output where you acn see the memory id of each of the objects you will see how they point to the same object and then in the third function its repointed to a new object in memory.

```
mylist: [1]
mylist id: 2636457271880
second id: 2636457271880
Second_list: [1, 2]
second id: 2636457271880
third list: [1, 2]
third id: 2636457271880
third list: [3]
third id: 2636457271944
mylist: [1, 2]
mylist id: 2636457271880
```